# Send email from Django in docker container

Tags: django, docker

I have deployed an existing application inside a docker container. The email service is now working any more.

I have exposed the email server port (587),  but still not working.

This is my django email configuration:

```
# EMAIL handler
EMAIL_HOST = "smtp.office365.com"
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = "email@email.com"
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = "pssword"
```

these are my container exposed ports:

```
docker run -d -p 8001:8020 -p 587:587  --name ...
587/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:587
8020/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:8001
```

I have tried to debug it, but it get stuck at the email send operation and does not retrieve nothing.

Does someone know what I am doing wrong?
UPDATE:

Dockerfile

```
# Dockerfile

FROM python:3.7-buster

# install nginx
RUN apt-get update 
# copy source and install dependencies
RUN mkdir -p /opt/app
RUN mkdir -p /opt/app/pip_cache
RUN mkdir -p /opt/app/djsr
COPY requirements.txt  /opt/app/
# COPY .pip_cache /opt/app/pip_cache/
COPY . /opt/app/
WORKDIR /opt/app
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt --cache-dir /opt/app/pip_cache
RUN yes yes | python manage.py collectstatic 
# RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /opt/app

# start server
EXPOSE 8020
STOPSIGNAL SIGTERM
CMD gunicorn django_react.wsgi:application  --user www-data --bind 0.0.0.0:8020 --workers 8 --timeout 400
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to add these lines :

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

Comment: i think it is a container issue. I am running another node.JS app which faces same issue after deployment in container...

Comment: It's working locally ?
Check if 587 port is open on the hosting server maybe.

Comment: it is open. It is working locally.  ```sudo netstat -ntlp | grep 587
tcp6       0      0 :::587                  :::*                    LISTEN      3934/docker-proxy
```

Comment: Try the connectivity from your container.
`nc -vz smtp.office365.com 587`

Comment: i think i cannot reach the port: ```# nc -vz smtp.office365.com 587
Warning: inverse host lookup failed for 40.101.84.226: Unknown host```

Comment: No it's juste a waring because your DNS resolver is not setup.
Can you show me your dockerfile ?
You may forgot to expose your port :
`EXPOSE 587`

Comment: thanks so much, i will check and add the dockerfile here. :)

Comment: I have added the dockerfile used to build the image.